# Inserting elements in a BST

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am trying to insert elements in a BST and not getting correct results.
Instead of getting all the array elements printed out, I only get `1,11,14` elements printed instead of entire array elements.

```
int arr[10] = { 11, 2, 4, 23, 1, 98, 88, 65, 33, 14 };
void insertNodeinBST(int data,node **root){

    node *new_n = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_n->leftChild = new_n->rightChild = NULL;
    new_n->data = data;
      //check if root is null
    if (*root == NULL) {
        *root = new_n;   
    }
    else if (data < (*root)->data){
        //if data is less than current root's data add it to left child
        insertNodeinBST(data, &(*root)->leftChild);
        (*root)->leftChild = new_n;
    }
    else {
      //if data is more than current root's data add it to right child
        insertNodeinBST(data, &(*root)->rightChild);   
        (*root)->rightChild = new_n;
    }

}

//print BST 
void printInorder(node *root){

        if (root == NULL)
            return;

        /* first recur on left child */
        printInorder(root->leftChild);

        /* then print the data of node */
        printf("%d ", root->data);

        /* now recur on right child */
        printInorder(root->rightChild);

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int i = 0;
    node *root = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        //inserting nodes
        insertNodeinBST(arr[i], &root);
    }
    printInorder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it, just a couple things in `insertNodeinBST()`:

You should only create the new node when `root` is `NULL`, otherwise, you keep creating a new node every time you visit a new node, looking for the place to insert:

```
//check if root is null
if (*root == NULL) {
    node *new_n = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_n->leftChild = new_n->rightChild = NULL;
    new_n->data = data;

    *root = new_n;
}
```

The code above takes care of inserting the new node, so you don't need the other assigns, change:

```
} else if (data < (*root)->data) {
    //if data is less than current root's data add it to left child
    insertNodeinBST(data, &(*root)->leftChild);
    (*root)->leftChild = new_n;
} else {
    //if data is more than current root's data add it to right child
    insertNodeinBST(data, &(*root)->rightChild);
    (*root)->rightChild = new_n;
}
```

to

```
} else if (data < (*root)->data) {
    //if data is less than current root's data add it to left child
    insertNodeinBST(data, &(*root)->leftChild);
} else {
    //if data is more than current root's data add it to right child
    insertNodeinBST(data, &(*root)->rightChild);
}
```

the recursive call will set the pointer to the new node when it reaches the correct empty node.

Comment: You're welcome.  You might also want to investigate the recursive BST insert node function that returns a node pointer, I think it looks much cleaner than this one that modifies the node * argument.  If you are interested, let me know and I will dig up my version and post it for you.

Comment: I did find solutions which return the node pointer on google. But I wanted to purposefully update the root pointer to better understand pointers. Although I do agree with you that solution which returns node pointer is much cleaner. Thanks!